# Mi funcion no me da el resultado

Tags: python, funciones, condiciones, variables, print

> La idea del programa es que detecte (entre tres numeros) cual es el mayor, menor y el del medio (o sea ordenar los numeros de manera ascendente)

> **Mi código:**

```
    def numeros_Mmc (num1,num2,num3):
    if num1 > num2 and num3:
        numM = num1
    elif num2 > num1 and num3:
        numM = num2
    elif num3 > num1 and num2:
        numM = num3
    

    if num1 < num2 and num3:
        numm = num1
    elif num2 < num1 and num3:
        numm = num2
    elif num3 < num1 and num2:
        numm = num3
    

    if num1>num2>num3:
        numc = num2
    elif num3>num1>num2:
        numc = num1
    elif num2>num3>num1:
        numc = num3
    elif num3>num2>num1:
        numc = num2
    elif num1>num3>num2:
        numc = num3
    elif num2>num1>num3:
        numc = num1
    
    return (numM,numm,numc)

def main ():
    num1 = int(input("Ingrese el primer número: "))
    num2 = int(input("Ingrese el segundo número: "))
    num3 = int(input("Ingrese el tercer número: "))

    orden = numeros_Mmc(num1,num2,num3)

    print ("El numero mayor es ",orden[0],", el menor es ",orden[1],"y el central 
    es",orden[2])



main ()
```

> Si bien el código en si cuando lo ejecuto no me da error, los resultados si estan mal.
> No se si es un error en las cuentas que hize (porque son varias), pero las revise en un cuaderno antes y creo yo que ese no es el problema. Cuestion que no se muy bien cual es el error, si alguien me puede ayudar gracias.

Comment: Tus condiciones están mal, por ejemplo esta `if num1 > num2 and num3:` esto quiere decir que si `num1` es mayor a `num2` y si `num3` es diferente de `0` entonces entra a esa condición. No estás evaluando que `num1` sea mayor a `num3`. Debería ser `if num1 > num2 and num1 > num3:`

Comment: Claro, tiene sentido. Ahi lo arregle teniendo en cuenta lo que me dijiste. Puse como condicion: if num1 > num2 and num1 > num3:

Comment: Pero lo que quiero decir, es que todas las condiciones donde calculas `numM` y `numm` están mal, hay que cambiarlas todas.

Comment: Sisi, obviamente lo cambie en todas las condiciones. Igual gracias por la aclaracion y por la ayuda!

Comment: Ok, entonces creo que ya funcionó tu código. Como fue un error tipográfico y se resolvió en los comentarios he votado por cerrar la pregunta, es probable que otros usuarios también lo hagan. Si deseas eliminar o cerrar tu pregunta lo puedes hacer manualmente. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

ES correcto lo que dice @HeyTalePazguato. Tienes las condiciones mal.

Si tú colocas ***"num 1 > num 2 and num 3"*** lo que el programa hará será validar que efectivamente num 1 sea mayor a num2, sin embargo, verá si num3 es diferente que 0 ***¿porqué?***

> Porque cuando colocas algo como **"if num3"** el interprete lo que hace es validar que la variable tiende a ser falso, en palabras sencillas, que no sea 0.

Es por eso que tambien deberías validar **"num 1 > num3"**

Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de cómo debería quedar tu función. según los requerimientos que planteas.

```
def numeros_Mmc(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 <= num2 and num1 <= num3:
        menor = num1
        if num2 <= num3:
            medio = num2
            mayor = num3
        else:
            medio = num3
            mayor = num2
    elif num2 <= num1 and num2 <= num3:
        menor = num2
        if num1 <= num3:
            medio = num1
            mayor = num3
        else:
            medio = num3
            mayor = num1
    else:
        menor = num3
        if num1 <= num2:
            medio = num1
            mayor = num2
        else:
            medio = num2
  mayor = num1

    return menor, medio, mayor

resultado = numeros_Mmc(4, 1, 7)
print(resultado) # (1, 4, 7)
```

Comment: Asi mismo lo correjí. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

También podrías añadir los números a una lista y hacer uso de la función integrada `sorted()` que por defecto, dado una lista de enteros, los ordena en orden ascendente:

```
num1 = int(input("Ingrese el primer número: "))
num2 = int(input("Ingrese el segundo número: "))
num3 = int(input("Ingrese el tercer número: "))

orden = sorted([num1, num2, num3])

print (f"El numero mayor es {orden[0]}, el menor es {orden[2]} y el central  es {orden[1]}")
```